# Привязка своей формы для mailchimp wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть своя форма на сайте, сейчас мне нужно сделать, что бы отправка с данной формы записывала емейлы в mailchimp. Я установил плагин "Mailchimp for wordpress" и хочу узнать, как привязать мою форму, написанную руками, к mailchimp'у. То есть, после того как клиент нажимает кнопку "submit", то, что он ввел, падало в этот плагин.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было написать функцию, которая использует CURL, чтобы отправлять что получил в mailchimp через MailChimp API

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от кода формы. Если это что то наподобие формы для контакта.. то используйте Contact Form 7 и extension для Mailchimp. Мало информации/описание проблемы